# Placing something above an ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a custom portfolio gallery for my website, and I'm having an issue.

I want to make the gallery slide up when you click on a thumbnail, but without putting every image on the page right away. The page is set up something like this:

```
  [  main img   ]
(hidden placeholder)
  [1][2][3][4][5]
```

And the code should work like this:

1. Click on thumb to get `SRC` attribute
2. Place `<img src="original+_lg.jpg" />` above `(hidden placeholder)` (`<div id="placeholder">`)
3. Subtract `500px` from `margin-top` to slide up the image using CSS3

I tried writing the script myself, but I'm terrible with jQuery, and it didn't turn out so well. I managed to change the margin-top, but only manually, not the loop, which would be ideal.

The code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#thumb").click(function() {
    $("#mask").css({
        "margin-top":"-500px"
    });
    $('img#placeholder').attr('src',function(i,e){
        return e.replace("slides/thumb_lg.jpg");
    })
});
```

});

Which, as you can see, doesn't really work.

I was pretty disappointed that I couldn't figure this out, because I managed to actually decently code jQuery for the home page (http://beta.jacobbearce.com/)

I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

EDIT: A little clarification:

It'd be great for this script to get the SRC attribute of the thumb you click on, remove the last four characters (to get rid of .jpg), then add on `_lg.jpg` to display the correct, large image, put the new `<img src="original+_lg.jpg">` above the placeholder div, and then subtract 500px from the margin-top so it slides up to show the new image. A little complex, I know, but this would be best for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could it be that you only have one argument in your `replace` function, when you should have two? Could you post the corresponding HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to insert the new image into the DOM before the hidden placeholder:

```
$('#placeholder').before( '<img src="original+_lg.jpg" />' );
```

then adjust the margin as needed.

Comment: Can you clarify the second part? How did you attempt to change the margin when it didn't work?

Comment: What I'd like to do is have it do some math, so when you add a new picture, it has something like `margin = originalMargin -500px` because every time you add an image, it's going to have to move up an additional 500px to show the image.

Comment: @Rev: As long as the image is not floated, it will make room for itself in the layout.

Comment: The way it's designed it's supposed to have the margin change. The div the image is in has overflow:hidden; and a larger div inside, to contain the images, that's supposed to slide up ( by having it's margin change) when clicking a thumbnail.